# Strategies to solve multivariate limits involving absolute values

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

In an exercise on differentiability, I started with this hypothesis:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{y})x^3y+(2x-1)x^2y^2}{\|(x,y)\|(|y+1|x^2+y^2)} \neq 0$$

But I couldn't justify that statement. I've tried to approach (0,0) through the curve $\alpha(t) = (t,t)$ when $t \to 0^{+}$ to get rid of the absolute value in the denominator (to no avail):

$$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{t})t^4+(2t-1)t^4}{\sqrt{2}t(t^3+2t^2)} = \lim_{t\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{t})+2t-1}{\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{t}} = 0$$

Any hint as to how to approach this exercise?

Comment: What is $\|(x,y)\|$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Then if we set $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, your fraction appears to be $$\frac{O(r^4)}{r^3+O(r^4)}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the answer almost ready. Use the fact that $-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$ and then use the Squeeze Theorem to show that your limit is $0$.

I.e., you would have $-1\leq\sin{(\frac{1}{t})}\leq 1$ from where
\begin{equation*}
\frac{-1+2t-1}{\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{t}}\leq \frac{\sin{(\frac{1}{t})}+2t-1}{\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{t}} \leq \frac{1+2t-1}{\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{t}}
\end{equation*}
Now take limit of both sides $\lim_{t\to 0^+}{}$ and you get the two sides equal $0$. By Squeeze Theorem, the middle one is also $0$.